# How to make a year select in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I would like to make a select  that show the years from 1960 to current year,so after i submit it I should have a string like :1989.

I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
 ->add('years', 'date', array(
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'years'       => range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 30, -1)))
```

Comment: The date type will return `\DateTime` instances. If you only want to be able to retrieve the year, you should take a look into the choice type.

Comment: I tried this :->add('years', 'choice', array(
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'years'       => range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 30, -1))) but it doesn't work

Comment: You should take a look at the available options of the coice type.There is neither a `format`, `widget` nor `years` option for the choice type. And having a format like `yyy-MM-dd` doesn't make any sense at all if you only want to have the year.

Comment: can you please help me with code?  I am beginner in symfony .Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty easy.
If after submiting form you want a year string just generate a array of years since 1960, like this:

```
class MyClassType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('year',
                'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType',[
                'choices' => $this->getYears(1960)
            ])
            # or (for symfony <= 2.7):
            # ->add('year', 'choice', ['choices' => $this->getYears(1960)])

        ;
    }

    private function getYears($min, $max='current')
    {
         $years = range($min, ($max === 'current' ? date('Y') : $max));

         return array_combine($years, $years);
    }
}
```

Template:

[image]

After form submit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the DateInterval class PHP with this pattern :

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P30Y');
```

with your reference Date start